# Adding JPanel to JList

Tags: java, swing, list, jpanel

I want to add a custom objects that extend `JPanel` into a JList. Everything is fine, but I can not interact with them. For example, I can not type in the `JTextField` which is added on panel. I Use `DefaultListModel<ListItem = new DefaultListModel<ListItem>();` Plase help.

This is custom Object

```
public class ListItem extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField textField;

public ListItem() {
    setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][grow]", "[30px:n:30px][30px:n:30px][30px:n:30px]"));

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    add(lblNewLabel, "cell 0 0,alignx trailing");

    textField = new JTextField();
    add(textField, "cell 1 0,growx");
}
```

This is the renderer

```
public class ListItemRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<Object>{

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Object> list, Object value, int index,
        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    Component component = (Component) value;

    if(isSelected)
        component.setBackground(Color.RED);

    return component;
}
```

This is how I create List

```
list = new JList<ListItem>(addedItems);
```

And

```
ListItem temp = new ListItem();
addedItems.addElement(temp);
list.setCellRenderer(new ListItemRenderer());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to add a custom objects that extend JPanel into a JList. Everything is fine, but I can not interact with them. For example, I can not type in the JTextField which is added on panel.

That is because a Jlist does not hold or show components but rather only rendering of components. If you want a list like object that holds components that can be *edited*, that the user can interact with, then either create your own -- using a JPanel that uses GridLayout and holds a grid of your components, or use a JTable that has at least two columns, one (the "label") that's not editable, and the other (the "text field") that is.

Comment: "either create your own" what you mean by this, create my own list?

Comment: @ЂорђеЂашић: Yes, sort of. If you have a small number of cells, then create a JPanel that uses GridLayout, add your cells to it, and place it inside of a JScrollPane.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe this will sound like newbie question, but how do I create my own list? JList list = new JList() ? I already do that.. ?

Comment: @ЂорђеЂашић: it's just as I explained in the comment above.

Comment: Yeah seems like this is the way to do. Thanks a lot.